# Issue setting static ETH0 IP BeagleBone Black Version C Debian Preloaded

Tags: networking, debian, beagleboneblack

Settings in /etc/network/interfaces seems to have no effect on my BeagleBone Black Version C. I want to set my beaglebone black's ethernet IP address to a static IP as I have done with all my other internet-of-things devices running Debian. I edited /etc/network/interfaces as I have before, but I do not see any changes via ifconfig. This is after a restart of networking AND a restart of the beaglebone. I have googled somewhat, and posted to the beaglebone forums after searching them, and I still do not have a solution. I noticed a commented line in interfaces suggesting that the settings are set via an init script, but this is where I get a little lost. I have moderate knowledge of Debian, but I have not peeled back enough layers apparently. I am connecting my beaglebone black via ethernet connector. WIFI is a beast I will tackle later.

I set my router to reserve a specific IP based on MAC ID, but I would like to know what I am missing here.

```
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.103
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, and it was similar, and earlier to what user1486241 suggested below. I apologize for not following up. I thought I had.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the auto line

```
auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

(Just for diagnosis) - Also remove the gateway line from it 
and after you get the connection run this command to add the gateway

```
    root prompt :) #
route add default gateway 192.168.0.1
```

i was playing around a lot with networking on it so i got the answer. Hope this resolve your issue do post.

Comment: Thank you user1486241. I did not know about route add as you suggested. Thank you so very much! I got this working shortly after I posted and failed to follow up, and I thought I had. What I did was exactly the same.

Comment: Pleasure. I think this problem is still bugging many people.  Thank you selecting my answer as correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Do the configurations in wicd. Run "wicd-client" which opens GUI to make the configuration. Apparently wicd configurations overwrite what you do in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: This was our problem. We don't need wicd's functionality, so `dpkg -l | grep -i wicd` shows what's installed. For us, `apt-get remove wicd-gtk wicd-curses wicd-cli wicd-daemon python-wicd` (and `apt-get autoremove` for good measure).

Comment: Thank you Milind Dumbare and especially @JimB This saved my life and now static address is preserved during hotplugging

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to setting the ipaddress to be static on boot. Even without a ethernet jack plugged in, which was my issue.

**Caution: this is hacky, and there probably better streamlined approach**

Edit the */opt/scripts/boot/autoconfigure_usb0.sh* script

line 92 and 139 set the usb0 default ipaddress

```
/sbin/ifconfig usb0 ${deb_usb_address} netmask ${deb_usb_netmask} || true
```

insert the following line after it, in both places

```
/sbin/ifconfig usb0 ${deb_usb_address} netmask ${deb_usb_netmask} || true
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.123 netmask 255.255.255.0 || true
```

then it will boot up with that as the static IP address even if you don't have anything plugged it.